# @Override annotation in Eclipse not going away

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

I referred to other similar questions and tried the solution but somehow did not work for me. So, basically I have  a class which implements an interface (API). There is `@Override` annotation for which `Eclipse` complains. I ensure it used `JDK 1.6` compliance level; Changed the Error to Warnings in Eclipse `Preferences->Java Compiler->Error/Warnings->Annotations` and still it gives me compilation problems. Workaround is to comment `@Override` though I would like to resolve this. What could I be missing ? Eclipse Kepler with `JDK 1.7` on Mac.

@Bohemian It's a private library.

```
package mypackage;

import somepckage.model.Session;

public interface SessionDirectoryNotification {
    public void onChange (Session session) {
    }
 }

public class MyHandler implements SessionDirectoryNotification {
     @Override
     public void onChange (Session session) {
       ... my code...
     }
}
```

Comment: Show the interface and your method signature. The error may be legitimate

Comment: @Bohemian here you go-
'code'@Override <=i have to comment this to go past compilation error
 public void onChange (Session session) {
         synchronized (sessionNotificationMap) {
   
  print(session);sessionNotificationMap.notifyAll();
  }
 } 'code'
'code' public interface SessionDirectoryNotification {
 public void onChange(Session session);
}'code'

Comment: And which classes/interfaces is your class extending/implementing?

Comment: My class is implementing 'onChange' defined in 'SessionDirectoryNotification' as shown above. Sorry, could not fix the formatting even though I tried by referring to stackoverflow docs. I have been a reader for too long and recently tried to post questions and interact more. It is surprising that with < 15 reputation, one can't answer or contribute to any other discussions.

Comment: Google shows no hits for `SessionDirectoryNotification`, so it must be a class from a private library. Please post the definition of `onChange` method as coded in the `SessionDirectoryNotification` class, verbatim. Do not type it in - copy-paste it so there are no typographical errors.

Comment: @Bohemian I edited the post above to make the code bit more legible. Hope this is better to read. Thanks for your comments and time !

Answer (score 0):

@Override annotation - is an indicator for java compiler, that you intend to override or implement a method. This helps to avoid mistakes. 
For example, method signature in the interface has changed, hence you have to change instance method. In this case Eclipse will highlight an error.

```
public interface ISome {
     void methodToImplement(int param);
}

public class SomeClass {

     // compile, method signature is identical to the signature of the interface
     @Override 
     void methodToImplement(int param); 

     // won't compile, cause method signature is different in the interface
     //@Override
     //void methodToImplement();

     // won't compile, cause there is no such method in the interface
     //@Override
     //void missing();
}
```

Check if you have this kind of error. If it's not the case, provide some code.

Comment: Please see my response above. Override is correct but Eclipse somehow complains about this annotation. This seems more of Eclipse issue since I can easily build it via maven and command line. if I uncomment @Override, I get following message from Eclipse (If I hover over Red mark indication compilation problem)
_italic_ The method onChange(Session) of type SessionDirectoryNotificationHandler must override a superclass 
 method

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have edited the post to make code bit more legible using code constructs. I realize when adding comment, code can't be formatted since the HTML editor appears only for Answers and while Editing original post. Getting used to posting comments now.

Answer (score 0):

You are (probably) importing the wrong `Session` class.

Make sure the following line is in your implementing class:

```
import somepckage.model.Session;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I double checked and import is correct. This can't go wrong since I am using Eclipse Auto Completion. In fact, I removed import and then Eclipse complained about missing import. Added it and now `@override` problem. Eclipse suggests to remove this annotation. Earlier, I was able to resolve it with Eclipse settings described in a different workspace. When I switched to this workspace, this problem resurfaced. I work on multiple work spaces. I can probably tinker around more and resolve this but intent of asking this question was to get some relevant pointers.